# How to change the scale of a page? (radaee pdf)

Tags: java, android

I use radaee pdf library.
(PDFLayoutDual or PDFLayoutVert) I want to set a permanent size so that all pdf documents regardless of the size were Stretch the width of the screen.
How to implement it?
The document should always stretch, an example of magnification: double-click on the document stretches the document to the width of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

**PDFLayoutVert** already fits according to screen width, the default behavior of the single/dual mode is to fit according to the screen height, so that you do not need to scroll vertically to view the whole page.

To fit the page according to the screen width, (if you have a professional or premium license) you need to comment the following line in **PDFLayoutDual.vLayout**:

```
//if( m_scale_min > scale ) m_scale_min = scale;
```

instead of:

```
if( m_scale_min > scale ) m_scale_min = scale;
```

You can do this either by modifying the original file, or extending it and override **vLayout** method